# cannot create product attribute (taxonomy) and add terms on the same execution

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, terms

I have the following functions to create a global product attribute and populate it with terms based on data from an API.

```
protected function getOrCreateAttribute($slug, $name)
    {
        $taxonomyId = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($slug);
        if (!empty($taxonomyId) && $taxonomyId > 0) {
            return $taxonomyId;
        }
        $taxonomyId = wc_create_attribute([
            'name' => $name,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'type' => 'select',
        ]);
        if ($taxonomyId instanceof \WP_Error) {
            throw new Exception($taxonomyId->get_error_message());
        }
        return $taxonomyId;
    }

    protected function getOrCreateTerm($slug, $name, $taxonomySlug)
    {
        $term = get_term_by('slug', $slug, $taxonomySlug);
        if ($term === false) {
            clean_taxonomy_cache($taxonomySlug);
            /** @var \WP_Term|\WP_Error $term */
            $term = wp_insert_term($name, $taxonomySlug, ['slug' => $slug]);
            clean_term_cache($term->term_id, $taxonomySlug);
        }
        if ($term instanceof \WP_Error) {
            throw new Exception($term->get_error_message());
        }
        return $term;
    }
```

Now in my data processing loop I'm trying this way to create an attribute if it doesn't exist, and the same for each term in that attribute.

Finally I'm trying to add them to the product.

```
            foreach ($featuresGroup->Features as $feature) {
                $taxonomyName = $feature->Feature->Name->Value;
                $taxonomySlug = $this->slugger->slugify($taxonomyName);
                $taxonomyId = $this->getOrCreateAttribute($taxonomySlug, $taxonomyName);
                $attribute = wc_get_attribute($taxonomyId);

                $termsToSet = [];
                $termName = $feature->PresentationValue;
                $termSlug = $this->slugger->slugify($termName);
                $term = $this->getOrCreateTerm($termSlug, $termName, $attribute->slug);

                $termsToSet[] = $term->term_id;
                if (array_key_exists($attribute->slug, $productAttributes)) {
                    $productAttribute = &$productAttributes[$attribute->slug];
                    $productAttribute->set_options($termsToSet);
                } else {
                    $wcProductAttribute = new \WC_Product_Attribute();
                    $wcProductAttribute->set_name($attribute->name);
                    $wcProductAttribute->set_id($attribute->id);
                    $wcProductAttribute->set_visible(1);
                    $wcProductAttribute->set_options($termsToSet);
                    $productAttributes[$attribute->slug] = $wcProductAttribute;
                }
            }
```

Now my problem here is that I have to run the same piece of code multiple times to actually get a result and I'm not sure why. Normally on the first run I'm encountering an error

`Invalid taxonomy`

During the `wp_insert_term` execution which instead of creating the `WP_Term` produces a `WP_Error`

However if I run it multiple times, everything eventually gets generated.

I'm not sure what's going on here.

I've tried clearing the caches for terms and taxonomies in case it was failing due to cache, to no avail.

Let me add some info for example the `$attribute` variable before `getOrCreateTerm` function call

[image]

And the result of `taxonomy_exists` shows false during `wp_insert_term` even though it was clearly defined before and has an ID

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added a quick check with

`taxonomy_exists($slug)`

and if it doesn't exist before adding the terms I use

`register_taxonomy($taxonomySlug, 'product')`

This seems to have allowed creation of all terms in one go.